Why is the Rate Limit of 2 orders/sec not working with Resilience4j and Spring Boot?
I'm using Resilience4j's RateLimiter with Spring Boot to limit the rate of processing orders to 2 orders per second. However, the rate limiter doesn't seem to be working as expected, and all orders are being processed without delay.
Here's a brief overview of my setup. What could I be missing?
@Component
@Slf4j
public class OrderProcessor {

    @RateLimiter(name = "orderRL", fallbackMethod = "orderRateLimitFallback")
    public void process(Order order) {
        log.info("Processing Order: " + order);
    }

    public void orderRateLimitFallback(Order order, Throwable t) {
        log.warn("Rate limit exceeded for order: {}. Please try again later.", order);
    }
}

@Slf4j
@Component
public class OrderService {
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    private OrderProcessor orderProcessor;

    public void processOrders() {
        try {
            InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("orders.json");
            List<Order> orders = objectMapper.readValue(is, new TypeReference<List<Order>>() {});
            log.info("Order size:" + orders.size());
            for (Order order: orders) {
                orderProcessor.process(order);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error processing orders", e);
        }
    }
}

build.gradle dependecies:
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.3.2'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:3.3.2'
implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-ratelimiter:2.2.0'
implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-annotations:2.2.0'
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'

application.properties:
resilience4j.ratelimiter.metrics.enabled=true
resilience4j.ratelimiter.instances.orderRL.register-health-indicator=true
resilience4j.ratelimiter.instances.orderRL.limitForPeriod=2
resilience4j.ratelimiter.instances.orderRL.limitRefreshPeriod=1s
resilience4j.ratelimiter.instances.orderRL.timeoutDuration=1s
resilience4j.ratelimiter.instances.orderRL.allow-health-indicator-to-fail=true
resilience4j.ratelimiter.instances.orderRL.subscribe-for-events=true
resilience4j.ratelimiter.instances.orderRL.event-consumer-buffer-size=50


Define "not working"

If you have not already done so, I recommend that you read [ask].

the rate limiter doesn't seem to be working as expected This just is not enough to understand what the problem is. Please add as many details as possible.
